# Is there any way to get a specific partial similar to get_val()?

Tags: openmdao

As the title states, the get_val() function allows the user to retrieve the value of a input, output or residual. Is the anything like a get_partial(of=..., wrt=...) that allows a user to retrieve a derivative? Or what would be the best way to go about retrieving that from the problem or model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting a general derivative in a system, the recommended practice is to use the [compute_totals](https://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/latest/features/core_features/working_with_derivatives/compute_totals.html) method.
Even if you just want to look at a partial derivative, you can use the `of` and `wrt` arguments to point to just the specific partial. You'll get a total, but it should be equal to the partial.

The general debugging practice for looking at partials is to use [check_partials](http://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/3.10.0/features/core_features/working_with_derivatives/approximating_partial_derivatives.html). This will give you full values of all the partials to look at. But if you need an algorithmic approach as part of a run script, then use compute_totals.

OpenMDAO stores outputs, so obtaining those is a matter of getting a value that's already there (hence `get_val`).
For derivatives, depending on the way in which OpenMDAO is used, there's no guarantee that the totals are present in memory, so they must be computed when needed.